# how to redirect Modern UI cancel button using Spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, spfx-extensions, newform

hi i want to redirect modern ui newwform.aspx page cancel button to cancel page ? how can we do it using extension i have extension code which inject Javascript but unable to find cancel selector click function

[image]

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot of cancel button by selecting "Inspect element"? I will help you with selector for it.

Comment: i tried it and able to get but how to write click function on this to redirect cancel to another page